# Runtime Error 9 : Subcript out of range

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to write a vba code to check if workbook(A).worksheet(a).cells(row1, colum1) = workbook (B).worksheet(b).cells(row2,colum2), then do some copying and further checking.
But encounter an error message "subscript out of range". 
Would anyone please help me on this?

**Following is the code:**

```
Sub check()
    Dim row1, row2, row1start, row2start, row1end, row2end
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    ws1 = Excel.Workbooks("A.xlsx").Worksheets("sheet1")
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet
    ws2 = Excel.Workbooks("B.xlsx").Worksheets("sheet2")
    row1start = 2
    row1end = 43
    row2start = 3
    row2end = 163
    For row1 = row1start To row1end
        For row2 = row2start To row2end
            If ws2.Cells(row2, "I") = ws1.Cells(row1, "H") Then
                ws1.Cells(row1, "I") = 0    'mark true
                ws1.Cells(row1, "M") = ws2.Cells(row2, "K")     'copy

                If ws1.Cells(row1, "C") = ws2.Cells(row2, "J") Then
                    ws1.Cells(row1, "N") = 0    'mark true
                Else
                    ws1.Cells(row1, "N") = ws2.Cells(row2, "J")     'copy
                End If
                Exit For    'if found, then exit 1st loop
            End If
        Next row2

        If row2 >= row2end Then     'if no match, assign value -1
            ws1.Cells(row1, "I") = -1
        End If

        If row2start < row2end Then     'reduce searching times for next row1
            row2start = row2 + 1
        End If   
    Next row1
End Sub
```

Comment: Which line is giving you the error?

Comment: For starters, you need Set with object variables: `Set ws1 = Excel.Workbooks("A.xlsx").Worksheets("sheet1")` for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subscript out of range means it can't find the specified workbook, worksheet or range. Check, double check and recheck your names. If you're getting the error on this: `ws1 = Excel.Workbooks("A.xlsx").Worksheets("sheet1")` try isolating the assignment of the workbook and the worksheet to find which is giving the error.

Just found the same thing as Rory; You must use `SET` for workbook, worksheet or range; or any object.

```
SET ws1 = Excel.Workbooks("A.xlsx").Worksheets("sheet1")
```

Comment: Hi D_Bester. Thank you for your kind help. Just for the benefit of others, the 2nd bug is that, my file name is A.xls, which probably don't support VBA(not sure). I saved the file as A.xlsm, plus using "set" it works.